# LINQ to Entities: Convert SQL Sub Select

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

**I got this figured out. 
No need to answer.
The system says I have to wait 8 hours before answering my own questions. But for now the answer is below:**

Here is the answer:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);    
var results = (from h in Histories
                join q in Quotes
                    on h.QuoteID equals q.QuoteID
                join a in Agencies
                    on q.AgencyID equals a.AgencyID             
                        where q.Status == "Inforce" &&   
                                q.LOB == "Vacant" &&        
                                q.EffectiveDate > startDate &&
                                h.Deleted == null &&
                                h.DeprecatedBy == null &&                                    
                                h.TransactionStatus == "Committed" &&                                        
                                a.DC_PLT_Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Wholesaler")
                        group new {h} by new {h.PolicyNumber} into g        
                        select new {                                
                            MaxHistoryID = g.Max (x => x.h.HistoryID),
                            comment = (from h2 in Histories
                                    where h2.HistoryID == g.Max (x => x.h.HistoryID)
                                    select h2.Comment).FirstOrDefault() 
                            }).ToList();
```

The key code was:

```
comment = (from h2 in Histories
                                    where h2.HistoryID == g.Max (x => x.h.HistoryID)
                                    select h2.Comment).FirstOrDefault()
```

We are in the process of converting SQL / Stored Procedures to LINQ to Entities statements.  And I can’t figure out the proper syntax for a sub select.

Currently I am converting this SQL:

```
declare @startDate DateTime
set @startDate = DATEADD(DD, -30, GETDATE())

select * from history where historyid in(     
select  MAX(h.historyid) as HistoryId 
    from  History h (nolock) 
    inner join Quote q (nolock) on h.QuoteID = q.QuoteID 
    inner join Agency (nolock) a on q.AgencyID = a.AgencyID
    inner join DC_PLT_EntityRoles er (nolock) on a.AgencyID = er.EntityID
    inner join DC_PLT_Roles (nolock) r on er.RoleID = r.RoleID
    where
          q.Status = 'Inforce' 
          and q.LOB = 'Vacant'  
          and q.EffectiveDate > @startDate 
          and h.Deleted is null --
          and h.DeprecatedBy is null --
          and h.TransactionStatus = 'Committed'
          and r.Name = 'Wholesaler'
    group by h.PolicyNumber)
```

As you can see the code above is made up of two select statements.  The main select (select * from history).. And a filter select (select  MAX(h.historyid)…)

I got the filter select working (See below):

```
var startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);    
var results = (from h in Histories
                join q in Quotes
                    on h.QuoteID equals q.QuoteID
                join a in Agencies
                    on q.AgencyID equals a.AgencyID             
                        where q.Status == "Inforce" &&   
                                q.LOB == "Vacant" &&        
                                q.EffectiveDate > startDate &&
                                h.Deleted == null &&
                                h.DeprecatedBy == null &&                                    
                                h.TransactionStatus == "Committed" &&                                        
                                a.DC_PLT_Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Wholesaler")
                        group new {h} by new {h.PolicyNumber} into g        
                        select new {                                
                            MaxHistoryID = g.Max (x => x.h.HistoryID)                           
                            }).ToList();
```

However I can’t figure out the proper syntax to set up the main select. (Basically getting the records from the History table using the HistoryID from the filter select.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, here is the code:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);    
var results = (from h in Histories
                        .Include("Quote")
                        .Include("Quote.Agency")                                    
                        where h.Quote.Status == "Inforce" &&     
                                h.Quote.LOB == "Vacant" &&      
                                h.Quote.EffectiveDate > startDate &&
                                h.Deleted == null &&
                                h.DeprecatedBy == null &&                                    
                                h.TransactionStatus == "Committed" &&                                        
                                h.Quote.Agency.DC_PLT_Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Wholesaler")                            
                        group new {h} by new {h.PolicyNumber} into g        
                        select new {
                            XMLData = (from h2 in Histories
                                        where h2.HistoryID == g.Max (x => x.h.HistoryID)
                                        select h2.XMLData).FirstOrDefault() 
                            }).ToList();
```

The key logic is:

```
select new {
                            XMLData = (from h2 in Histories
                                        where h2.HistoryID == g.Max (x => x.h.HistoryID)
                                        select h2.XMLData).FirstOrDefault() 
                            }).ToList();
```

Gotta love the Nested Query